# Where to set base font?

Tags: css, font-size

If I set a `font-size` on the `body` element, will that size also be 1em?

In other words, if I do:

```
body {
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 16px;
}
```

Can I be sure everywhere I use 1em it will equal 16px?

If the above is not the correct way, how else should I set a base font?

Sorry if base font is not the correct term.  I’m not sure what this technique is referred to as.  I believe it is similar a reset stylesheet, which overrides the browser's default styles.

Comment: you can use any CSS Reset stylesheet. search for mayor reset stylesheet

Comment: You mean this http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/?  The font-size there is 100%.  If I change it to 16px, that will be my 1em?  Does this need to be in a separate stylesheet?

Comment: @4thSpace: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16784379/1516616) for clarifications.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

What you are looking to achieve can be done with the rem unit.

An em unit is “Equal to the computed value of the ‘font-size’ property of the element on which it is used.” In your case 1em would be 16px on the `body` element. But, if you change the `font-size` on any element, `1em` on that element will equal the `font-size` of that element. If you use ems on `font-size`, it is relative to the `font-size` of the parent element. Thus if `p` was the child of `div`, and `font-size` on `div` was `12px`, then `font-size: 1em` on `p` would be `12px.`

On the other hand, a `1rem` is always equal to the computed value of the font-size of the root element. In HTML this is the `html` element. Thus the size is always consistent. See http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#rem-unit

Comment: In that case, the example code here is what I should be used http://css3clickchart.com/#rem-units?  And that will work/override anywhere I reference rem?  By override, I mean it will always revert to the font-size I specified in the html definition?

Comment: Say you do the following: html { font-size: 10px; } then any time you use 1rem it will equal 10px. The biggest issue is it doesn't work in IE8 and below.

Comment: The `rem` unit is the font size of the *root* element, which is always the `html` element (not the `body` element) in HTML documents.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela I mentioned that in both my original reply and comment.

Answer (score 0):

If you set the `font-size` for an element, then (assuming your CSS rule will be applied) the `em` unit has that value *for that element*.

You cannot change the meaning of `em` from what it means in CSS: it denotes the font size of the element for which it is used (except when used in a `font-size` declaration or in a `font` shorthand, where it denotes the font size of the parent element).

Setting `em` to a fixed value would defeat the very purpose of the unit: it is *meant* to vary by context and settings. If you would want to set `em` to `16px`, then just use the `px` unit instead of the `em` unit. If you think the numbers get too big then, you can use the `pc` (pica) unit: by [CSS3 Units](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#absolute-lengths), and in browser practice, `1pc` = `12pt` = `16px`.

Answer (score -1):

When defining the font-size property, an `em` is equal to the size of the font that applies to the parent of the element in question. If you haven't set the font size anywhere on the page, then it is the browser default, which is probably 16px.

So, by default `1em = 16px`, and `2em = 32px`. If you set a font-size of 20px on the body element, then `1em = 20px` and `2em = 40px`.

Note that the value 2 is essentially a multiplier of the current em size.

[Reference Link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-size)

Comment: Just to clarify some of the answers being posted, your answer is in disagreement with Rapture?  He is saying you cannot change the font size because it is in the browser stylesheet.

Comment: I have attached a reference link, you may verify it. Thanks

Comment: Defining font sizes in pixel is not accessible, because the user cannot change the font size from the browser. (For example, users with limited vision may wish to set the font size much larger than the size chosen by a web designer.) Therefore, avoid using pixels for font sizes if you wish to create an inclusive design.

Comment: What do you mean it is not accessible?  We can set the font size in px but the user may override it.  That doesn't mean it is always not accessible.  In the link you provided, why do they set font-size to 62.5% instead of just 10px?

Comment: Setting the font size in pixel values (px) is a good choice when you need pixel accuracy. A px value is static. This is an OS-independent and cross-browser way of literally telling the browsers to render the letters at exactly the number of pixels in height that you specified. The results may vary slightly across browsers, as they may use different algorithms to achieve a similar effect.

Comment: While the em is a very useful unit in CSS, since it can adapt automatically to the font that the reader chooses to use.

Comment: Moreover, The “em” is a scalable unit that is used in web document media. While Pixels are fixed-size units that are used in screen media. And The percent unit is much like the “em” unit, save for a few fundamental differences. First and foremost, the current font-size is equal to 100% (i.e. 12pt = 100%). While using the percent unit, your text remains fully scalable for mobile devices and for accessibility. [see reference link](http://kyleschaeffer.com/user-experience/css-font-size-em-vs-px-vs-pt-vs/)

Comment: You're just dodging my questions by quoting from the link you referenced.  If you can't put it into your own words, I won't select this as an answer.

Comment: I quote your question `Can I be sure everywhere I use 1em it will equal 16px?` an see my answer.. `If you haven't set the font size anywhere on the page, then it is the browser default, which is probably 16px. So, by default 1em = 16px, and 2em = 32px. If you set a font-size of 20px on the body element, then 1em = 20px and 2em = 40px.` Are u not getting this?

Comment: And if you set `16px` in body then `1em` equals to `16px`